Loading a Video File in Python inside WSL - Failed
We have a Python file. The python simply reads a video file which is saved on the same location as the Python file.
Here's the sample code:
import cv2

# Path to the MP4 video file
video_path = 'video.mp4'

# Create a VideoCapture object
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

# Check if the video was opened successfully
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error: Could not open video.")
else:
    print("Successful!")

But reading the video file didn't work and returns the printed text "Error: Could not open video.".
Is there something needed to be setup for this to work inside WSL?
The code above is a sample of normally reading a video file that is running if executed in Windows.
We wanted to do the same inside WSL.
